# Expand collapsed Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, ide

I have javascript source code that was not obscured, but compressed by collapsing. How can i expand it? Any tools/IDEs?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 2):

I once used with success UniversalIndent for this purpose: http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/

It also works as a notepad++ plugin, which was very useful for me.

If you are interested in doing a lot of Javascript programming, I can also recommend the Aptana Studio 3. From all the code editors I have ever tried, when it comes to Javascript this is the best one, offering code outlining and a primitive (but the best I've seen for Javascript) autocomplete functionality. It also has a Source Auto Format functionality that will help you auto indent the code.

You can more about the Aptana studio on the official site: http://aptana.com/products/studio3 . Please note that Aptana Studio 3 is a Beta product, but even so for me it was the best editor I could find.

Comment: Aptana studio is free or commercial?)

Comment: Aptana Studio is free and open source.

Comment: please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298439/opensource-free-html5-css3-javascript-ide about Aptana;)

Comment: @Edward83 thanks! I added an answer in there as well, with more details to that specific question.