# Opensource/free HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript IDE?

Tags: javascript, open-source, html, ide, css

What is the best open source/free HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript IDE?

Thank you!!!

Comment: WebStorm from www.jetbrains.com is excellent for JavaScript, because it supports ECMAScript 5, understands JsDoc perfectly (inheritance and all). It's the only IDE that actually does that.

Comment: WebStorm looks interesting, but it's not open and it's not free (except for education and open source developers).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most of the time when I write code I am programming C# applications using Visual Studio, which is my favorite IDE. However, when it comes to Javascript VS is quite poor. It does not support collapse to definitions (AKA code folding in other IDEs / editors), does not support code outlining and also has a very primitive and most of the times useless autocomplete.

Because of that, at some point I have started to search alternative tools for JS programming and the best I came across was **Aptana Studio**. It also has support for HTML and CSS (as well as for some server side languages like Ruby, PHP, Phyton), but I have only used it for JS and that is an area where it shines. It has very good code outlining and one of the best autocomplete implementations I have ever seen for Javascript (even thought it is still improvable).

Aptana Studio is based Eclipse and is available as a plugin or as a full package version. On their site they are saying that the next version is going to totally independent from Eclipse, which would make it a lot more light weight and more performant. However, the current Beta version of Aptana Studio 3 is still based on Eclipse.

You can find more on Aptana Studio 3 on the official page: http://aptana.com/products/studio3

Comment: I just started using Aptana Studio a couple days ago, and I've been thoroughly impressed.  Anyone know of plans to add HTML5 and CSS3 code completion?  Is there any way to manually add new tags and style rules to Aptana's definitions?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind. After following the link you posted, I see the Aptana team is hard at work on Aptana Studio 3, which is still in beta, but will have support for new HTML and CSS features.

Answer (score 9):

[(G)Vim](http://www.vim.org/) of course. While it might look spartanic at first, it's extremely powerful once you've become familiar with the way it works.

Comment: Provide examples, list of plugins and where to get them, show *how* vim is better than other editors, how to get started in vi, then this advice will be worthy. Otherwise it's just showing off how you're different, not helping the OP.

Answer (score 6):

The answers are likely to be subjective, but here are some choices:

- KompoZer
- Aptana
- Amaya

Here are the links: [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/), [Aptana](http://www.aptana.org/), [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/).
This also may help: an extensive [comparison of HTML Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors).

Answer (score 2):

I use [Komodo Edit](http://www.openkomodo.com/).  The latest version has code completion for HTML5 and CSS3, the JavaScript code completion can be adjusted depending on which JS libraries you use (eg. jQuery, prototype, YUI).

Answer (score 2):

Free and open-source? - [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There is Sublime Text 2 http://www.sublimetext.com/2 after few years with Aptana... I enjoy using it.

Comment: I know the question and answer is old, but: Sublime Text is great, however it is **not** open source, which was requested.