# Parse and Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, parsing

I'm thinking of creating a HTML5 app, which I also want to run well on iOS. I'm thinking of using parse.com as the backend, but apart from that I'm a little unsure where to start, can I use Adobe Dreamweaver with Parse? are there better options for creating a HTML5 app?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the Parse documentation, there aren't any specific tools to help you work with Parse in DreamWeaver.

If you're looking for a high-quality IDE for developing HTML5 and CSS3, see [this question about open source HTML5/CSS3 IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298439/opensource-free-html5-css3-javascript-ide).

Parse has blank XCode (for iOS), blank Android project (should work in Eclipse), and basic HTML5 project listed in their [QuickStart guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart).  With the blank HTML5 project you can use any IDE you want to do the editing, and then open it in your browser to test it out.